# Is there any categorical name for these kind of words?

Tags: etymology, idioms, history

Words which are derived from Sanskrit (which is a historical Indo-Aryan language and the primary liturgical language of Hinduism, Jainism and Buddhism) Or Hindi into English.

For example:

- avatar
- karma
- kama

What category are these words part of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that these are just *loanwords* or [*borrowed words*](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Words04/structure/borrowed.html) because English uses them in their almost original form. The process of this is:

> Loanwords are words adopted by the speakers of one language from a different language (the source language). A loanword can also be called a borrowing. The abstract noun borrowing refers to the process of speakers adopting words from a source language into their native language. "Loan" and "borrowing" are of course metaphors, because there is no literal lending process. There is no transfer from one language to another, and no "returning" words to the source language. The words simply come to be used by a speech community that speaks a different language from the one these words originated in.

Words can be borrowed from any language, such as Sanskrit or Hindi, but the term is not specific to them. Other borrowed words in English from Sanskrit can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Sanskrit_origin). Also, if you are interested in the process of how loan words are incorporated into another language, there is a good summary [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrowed_word).

Comment: @ simchona ..So there is no specific categorical name for them these are just borrowed words .Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Abid: Correct, although a loan word is technically a category.

Comment: @simchobna. Ya just figured it out. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think "loanword" is pretty standard for cases like this where the word is taken with no significant change in meaning, and preserving spelling/pronunciation so far as practical. You have this in your quoted text anyway, so I don't see why your first sentence proposes the less common "borrowed word" as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

From Sanskrit we have *karma* (deed, work). The word *Sanskrit* comes from the same Indo-European root.

- Hinduism & Buddhism. The total effect of a person's actions and conduct during the successive phases of the person's existence, regarded as determining the person's destiny.
- Fate; destiny.
- Informal. A distinctive aura, atmosphere, or feeling: There's bad karma around the house today.

are the meanings of *karma*.

[Read more.](http://www.answers.com/topic/karma#ixzz1Vw351bsn)
It is originally used. Nothing is derived. What is the question you wanted to ask?

I am really sorry. I missed it: loanwords or borrowed words which are adopted and completely or partly naturalized.

Comment: @ A.Uysal Thanks for your answer . simchona is just answered my question. thank you